# Learning extension methods

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I am learning extension methods and I am trying to write my first extension method. I want to use the System namespace and write an extension method using that.

My method is convert currency from GBPtoBGN.

In my Main method now all I want to use this extension method but I get a compiling error.

```
public static class ExtentionMethodConvertGBPtoBGN
{
    public static double ConvertGBPtoBGN(this ExtentionMethodConvertGBPtoBGN obj, double BGNmoney, double conversionrate)
    {
        return BGNmoney * conversionrate;
    }
}
```

The compiler throws an error.

Error   CS0721  'ExtentionMethodConvertGBPtoBGN': static types cannot be used as parameters

Comment: Why the basic tag?

Comment: Seems like you'd want `ConvertGBPtoBGN(this double BGNmoney, double conversionrate)`  so you could do `someDoubleValue.ConvertGBPtoBGN(conversionrate);`

Comment: @dedecos using extension tags require 1500 reputation. I think this is a basic question, as I am just starting with these.

Comment: @grozdeto oh I see. "basic" is a language though; the tag is not intended for elementary questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way to do that is:

```
public static class ExtentionMethodConvertGBPtoBGN
{
    public static double ConvertGBPtoBGN(this double obj, double conversionrate)
    {
        return obj * conversionrate;
    }
}
```

After `this` you need to use the type you want to extend. On that case, apparently you want to extend `double` functionality. And you use the `obj` (you named this way) from argument.

Answer (score 1):

The type after `this` needs to be the object you want the extension method to exist on.

So if you want this to work on a `double` it would need to be

```
public static double ConvertGBPtoBGN(this double obj, double BGNmoney, double conversionrate)
```

Comment: More likely it's the `BGNmoney` argument that `this` should be applied to as `obj` isn't even used.

Comment: @juharr yup was just about to update my answer with something along those lines, the current implementation of the method doesn't seem to make sense as an extension method (in my opinion anyways).

Comment: Thank you but how can I have an extension method on the Math dll? My idea is to have my extension method when i type Math.ExtentionMethodConvertGBPtoBGN?

Comment: @grozdeto That's not how extension methods work and you cannot add new methods to the Math class.

Comment: @grozdeto You don't have an extension method on a DLL. You have an extension method on a *type* -- in this case double or better yet decimal, since it's currency. You would type `15.99m.Convert...` and see extension methods on `decimal` whose names start with `Convert`. The name of the static extension method class is offstage. It could be anything that doesn't conflict with something else in its namespace.

Comment: Thank you guys for your time. I understand how it works now. It is on a type , not on a DLL, in the signature of the method I used this double obj, then when I initialized a variable I had my method which is what I wanted to do. 
I appreciate all your quick answers and the time you have taken to explain it to me.
So basically I can create a class, reference that class this ExampleClass obj and then I can have access to the method on that class correct?

Comment: @grozdeto The .cs file will need a 'using` for the namespace your extension method class is defined in. Visual Studio "Quick Actions and Refactorings" won't help you add the namespace for extension methods, unfortunately.

Comment: @EdPlunkett thank you. I have just created a test class with a simple method and no constructor.  I then used my extension method and used this TestClass obj.
Then in my main method i created an instance on the testclass and now can I see the additional method. 
Extension methods are so powerful.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like below two ways:
Lets, Conversion is the main conversion class:

```
public class Conversion
{

}
```

And, ExtentionMethodConvertGBPtoBGN is yor extensio class:

```
public static class ExtentionMethodConvertGBPtoBGN
{
   //extension mathod
    public static double ConvertGBPtoBGN(this Conversion obj, double BGNmoney, double conversionrate)
    {
        return BGNmoney * conversionrate;
    }

    //non-extension mathod
    public static double ConvertGBPtoBGN(double BGNmoney, double conversionrate)
    {
        return BGNmoney * conversionrate;
    }
}
```

Now you can call both ways:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var con = new Conversion();
        var result  = con.ConvertGBPtoBGN(10.0, 20.0);

        //or
        var result2 = ExtentionMethodConvertGBPtoBGN.ConvertGBPtoBGN(10.0, 20.0);
    }
```

Comment: It does not work, the compiler is giving an error. cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead 
it is because the non-extension method cannot be called when the class is initiated if the non-extension method is static

Comment: I checked it again, it is compiling properly.
Whole code below: